# AngularJS tutorial on Apache

Tags: angularjs, apache

I thought I should try and teach myself AngularJS.  I've got a few websites that could probably do with updating, so thought I could try and kill two birds with one stone by using one of these new-fangled frameworks! I know that my current hosts don't support Node.js, so all I want is to use Angular on a standard LAMP stack (although for dev purposes, I'm running XAMPP on Windows).

The [AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) says `If you want to run the preconfigured local web-server and the test tools then you will also need Node.js v0.10.27+.` - since I don't want to run the preconfigured web-server, or use their test tools, I skipped this step. I've been given the impression that Angular does not need Node.js to run at all - is this correct? I checked out the angular-phonecat files to `C:\Users\chris\htdocs\angularjs_tutorial\angular-phonecat\app` and set up a subdomain `http://angularjs.localhost`, mapped to `C:\Users\chris\htdocs\angularjs_tutorial\angular-phonecat`, so that 'http://angularjs.localhost/app/index.html' should work (i.e. matching the tutorial's URL).

When I go to that page, I see

```
Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}
```

instead of

```
Nothing here yet!
```

What else do I need to do?! The fact that I already had the Windows git client should indicate (I hope!) I'm not an utter technophobic luddite (most of my job is programming, but I'm a chemistry graduate originally) but it does slightly frustrate me that developers put barriers in place to people who aren't total experts (although I do recognise that, although developers can't support all possible combinations, there is often a fine line between this and supporting combinations of dependencies that are most common...)

**More info**

After running `git checkout -f step-0` (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00), the source code for `index.html` is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I note that there **isn't** a `bower_components` directory in the current directory - is this something handled by the preconfigured Node.js server, or is it a bug in the tutorial? Either way, what's the best way to proceed?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your Apache Server. If the AngularJS is not interpreted, is mostly because it didn't load (Incorrect script path, or simply not added at all) or your AngularJS contains an error somewhere else.

Comment: I know that angular is a client side framework, which is why I don't really understand why it gets interpreted correctly out of the box on the preconfigured node webserver, but not on Apache!

Comment: Did you check if the relative path to the AngularJS.js file changed ?

Comment: Hmm, the source code is looking for a `bower_components` directory, which actually doesn't exist... Maybe the preconfigured node server takes care of this :/

Comment: This is an old question..., but you need to run `bower install` this will install the packages managed by bower into the `bower_components` folder

Answer (score 0):

You are right that AngularJS don't need a nodejs as it's just a client side framework, from your description I would say that you don't have angularjs attached to your page and that's what you will most likely find in developer tools in your browser